# How do you detect and print the current drilldown in the CrystalReportViewer control?

Tags: crystal-reports

When using Business Objects' CrystalReportViewer control, how can you detect and manually print the report the user has currently drilled into? You can print this automatically using the Print() method of the CrystalReportViewer, but I want to be able to do a manual printing of this report.

It is possible to print the main ReportSource of the CrystalReportViewer, but I need to know what report the user has drilled into and then do a manual printing of that particular drill down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Crystal Reports you are using, but if it is XIR2 or earlier then this isn't possible.  I haven't used the newer versions so I can't tell you.  One thing that I've done to solve this in the past was to have the drill actually link to another report altogether.  It depends on how your viewers actually view the reports (either via a thick-client viewer, the developer, or the web portal) on whether this will work however.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### detect: yes!

webpage:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ... 
    ondrill="CrystalReportViewer1_Drill" 
    ondrilldownsubreport="CrystalReportViewer1_DrillDownSubreport" />
```

code behind:

```
 protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Drill(object source, CrystalDecisions.Web.DrillEventArgs e)
 {
  //drill from graph to list of elements
 }
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_DrillDownSubreport(object source, CrystalDecisions.Web.DrillSubreportEventArgs e)
 {
   //drill from main report to subreports
 }
```

### print current: no!

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_DrillDownSubreport(object source, CrystalDecisions.Web.DrillSubreportEventArgs e)
{
    reportDocument.OpenSubreport(e.NewSubreportName).ExportToHttpResponse(format, Response, true, title);
}
```

exporting subreports throws an exception "not allowed for subreports".

### solution

CrystalReportsViewer's button works also on drilldown...

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer    HasExportButton="true" ....
```